# Change parameter in MySQL request SELECT

Tags: mysql

I am trying to change 'from_user' with a parameter from the other table and it doesn't work but when I am using the same table it works like a charm:

```
 SELECT from_user, message_contents, message_read, to_user, date 
 FROM table1 
 WHERE date IN ( 
 SELECT MAX( date ) 
 FROM table1 
 WHERE to_user = 1 GROUP BY from_user 
 ) 
 ORDER BY from_user ASC , date DESC
```

but this one just show one record but not all latest ones:

```
 SELECT table2.`display_name`, message_contents, message_read, to_user, date 
 FROM table1, table2
 WHERE table1.`from_user` = table2.`ID`
 AND date IN ( SELECT MAX( date ) 
 FROM table1
 WHERE to_user = 1 GROUP BY from_user 
 ) 
 ORDER BY from_user ASC , date DESC
```

Can anybody help to change 'from_user' with table2.`display_name` parameter but to get all recent records from mySQL?

Comment: You are not changing only the parameter on the select statement as you have one more where condition on the second query besides changes on tables. Can you give more details about your tables and data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are joining two tables on `table1.from_user = table2.id`
So, if you don't want that table two to affect the number of rows than you can make a query like this:

```
SELECT 
     table1.from_user,
     table2.`display_name`, 
     message_contents, 
     message_read, 
     to_user, 
     date 
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.`from_user` = table2.`ID`
WHERE 
     date IN (SELECT MAX(date) FROM table1 WHERE to_user = 1 GROUP BY from_user) 
ORDER BY from_user ASC , date DESC
```

I added also `table1.from_user` on the select clause which will help you see the from users which don't have a display name.